# Removing any item from scrollview causes it to scroll upward a little

Tags: android, scrollview

I am populating a ScrollView with some views by calling this function. I remove any item from list and then call this function again to show the updated data, but it always causes scroll view to scroll upward a little. Please help.

```
void setInsurances(List<Insurance> insurances){
    containerInsurances.removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i < insurances.size(); i++) {
        Insurance insurance = insurances.get(i);
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.insurance_info_list_layout, containerContacts, false);
        ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title)).setText(insurance.getCompanyName());
        ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle)).setText(insurance.getSubscriberName());
        ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle_two)).setText(insurance.getRelationName());
        ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_snn)).setText(insurance.getSnn());

        ImageView imgMenu = ((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_del_insurance));

        itemView.setTag(i);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgMenu.setTag(i);
        imgMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        containerInsurances.addView(itemView);
    }
```

Comment: If you are recreating the `View`s every time then you will get this behaviour. Can't you update the data without recreating the `View`s?

Comment: Also, you aren't removing "any" item, you are removing "all" items from the `ScrollView`. There's a big difference in the meaning of these 2 words.

Comment: I have tried the "removeViewAt(position)" too. It also does the same.

Comment: Also there are many containers like this in a scrollview.

Comment: You could try to call `requestFocus()` on the `View` that you want to be on-screen. This may prevent the `ScrollView` from scrolling away from it.

Comment: tried but its also not working.

Comment: Dear thank you for your help. I have found the issue. The fragment which contains this code is inside a viewpager2 and now I have committed this same fragment in simple activity and the issue is gone. So I guess this issue is only when fragment is in side a ViewPager. Thankyou very much.

Comment: No problem. Glad you were able to solve your issue.